# Linking table columns to auto populated

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 tables on 2 different sheets (Table 1 on sheet 1 & Table 2 on sheet 2). I want to enter my information into table 1 and have that information automatically populate a new row into table 2. I forced the relationships to work by linking the first row of cells to table 1, but table 2 doesn't show the new row unless I drag the table down. How can I have the new row of table 1 show as a new row in table 2 automatically without the user having to do it?

Comment: As currently implemented an excel table can't resize itself based on cell referencing that changes. You should be see that it becomes problematic because others may put data in cells below or to the side of tables. If an excel table where to dynamically grow/shrink what becomes of the data underneath the table? You'll probably need to come up with a VBA/Office Script solution.

Comment: You can try to use Power Query to create relationship between Table 1 and Table, it will update automatically.

Comment: I will have additional information that will need to be entered. Basically what I am trying to do is have Sheet 1 be the bill of materials (BOM) for our project and on sheet 2 have a parts tracking table. So I want to pull the items from the BOM so the user doesn't have to re-enter the same information twice.

Answer (score 0):

If your Table2 on Sheet2 is just read only (i.e., users shouldn't overwrite formulas) , replace it with the following in a single cell:

`=VSTACK(Table1[#Headers],Table1)`

Use conditional formatting to mimic table alternate shading.

Comment: I have the need for the filtering and sorting that the table offers and I will have additional information that will need to be entered.

Basically what I am trying to do is have Sheet 1 be the bill of materials (BOM) for our project and on sheet 2 have a parts tracking table. So I want to pull the items from the BOM so the user doesn't have to re-enter the same information twice.

Since this is a large project (we are building an entire vehicle) I need to be able to filter and sort the table to find parts.

Comment: Ah, the BOM would be a lookup table. You could have your two tables, have one column use data validation using BOM as source, and have other columns look up related BOM information based on the data validation selection. Some Table 2 columns will need to be lookup formulas but other columns could be open for data entry.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do but I can't get Table 2 to update with a new row when a new row is entered into Table 1. I have to manually drag the table field down to show the next row. I'd share the workbook with you but I'm not sure how.

Comment: That won't happen without vba and I must be missing something. If BOM table is only a lookup table, why would you need table 2 add a row when BOM has a row added? Can you clarify your original post to show  your desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry, the BOM table is not a lookup table. It is a growing list where items are entered as they come in/are ordered for the project, it is not finalized. I thought you meant using the "lookup" function for the parts tracking table.